# How to use "Could" for the following sentences

Tags: modal-verbs, time

1. He could come by car(=May be he will come by car)
2. He could come by car(to talk about the past)

Then how can I know whether someone is talking about past or future event? If it is wrong then please explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to tell from the context whether the past or the future is being referred to.

"He could come by car or by bus." (future)

"I told him that he could come by car, as there were plenty of parking spaces." (past)

"He could have come by car if he could have found someone to drive." (past)

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about the past, you need one more verb!

> He could *have* come by car (possibility shown in the past).

On the other hand,

> He *could* come by car (future probability)

is already clear to you.